# how to Translate Layout bottom to top from current Position to top outside the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-animation

In My Application i am animating the View from current Position to top (above the screen height).

I am Using this code to translate it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromYDelta="0" 
        android:toYDelta="-100" 
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

But still the animation is not good in view. So What Should i have to do to make it translate as i want ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="300"/>
```

try this one...